# Testing on TravisCI

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, travis-ci

I have come to know about TravisCI. It's great for testing syntactical bugs and resolving them but if that's the only functionality it provides, then I think Travis isn't worth it for testing. My only question is, does TravisCI automatically tests the code for exceptions/errors which might occur when the user is using the app? Are their any pre-requisits for this?

Comment: By "syntactical bugs" do you mean bugs that mean the code doesn't even build? No, CI in general is about more than that - it's about running whatever tests you've written. You do need to write the tests yourself though - whether those are unit tests, integration tests or something else. (And yes, I'd expect that to be trickier in terms of testing a mobile application than more "pure logic" code.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm worried that I understand your question correctly.

TravisCI is a combination of builder and test *runner*, not a monkey-testing program. You need to write code for Andoid unit-test and autonomous UI test based on your service logic, and also need to use additional app feedback program if you want to get information(stacktrace) of some error occured from users.

To write a unit test, see the official Android tutorial at below link.
https://developer.android.com/training/testing.html

Also, you can command monkey testing.
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html

And, in order to get error feedback, there are many projects and services to do this. Android Play Store developer console provides in ANR & Crashes menu. Or, [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) provides errors in more arranged manner. Consider [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) if you are in a security-sensitive company as it allows you to install to your own server. When user got crash, stacktraces will be automatically collected.

Comment: What is monkey-testing?

Comment: So for monkey testing, we don't have to write any testing code?

Comment: Yes but I mean TravisCI is not for that.